# Why is that !isset does not seem to work?

Tags: php, validation, forms, isset

I am new to the world of PHP and have put together a form that multiplies an entered value. However when I attempt to validate if a person has not entered any values to return an error message, it does display the message. My code below. Appreciate if you could also suggest improvements.

```
<?php

$counter = 0;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $start = $_POST["start"];
    $end = $_POST["end"];
    $multiply = $_POST["multiplication"];

// if($_POST["start"] == "" && $_POST["end"] == "" && $_POST["multiplication"] == "") {
    // print "Please enter some values";
// }

if(!isset($_POST["start"], $_POST["end"], $_POST["multiplication"])) {
    print "Please enter some values";

}

// for($start;$start<$end;$start++) {
    // $counter = $counter +1;
    // $multiplication = $counter * $multiply;
    // print "$counter <br />";
    // print "$counter multiplied by $multiply = $multiplication <br />";

// }

}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Multiplication</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="multiply" method="post" action="multiplication_sample.php">
        <input type="text" name="start" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["start"])) { print $start; }  ?>">
        <input type="text" name="end" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["end"])) { print $end; } ?>">
        <input type="text" name="multiplication" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["multiplication"])) { print $multiply; } ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

for($start;$start<$end;$start++) {
    $counter = $counter + 1;
    $multiplication = $counter * $multiply;
    print "$counter multiplied by $multiply = $multiplication <br />";
}

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like the form to display the message if the user does not specify any values for each of the form fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that `isset` will make sure a variable is not `NULL`, however, "blank" is not the same as null. If you submit a form with blank values, the variable is still being set, it is just empty.

Comment: So the code below the only way to validate the empty form fields?

if($_POST["start"] == "" && $_POST["end"] == "" && $_POST["multiplication"] == "") {
print "Please enter some values";
}

So when do form fields have the value NULL? 

Is it just checkboxes and radiobuttons that have a NULL value?

Comment: I believe checkboxes do NOT send a value unless checked. Radio buttons, by their very nature, should always have a value.

Comment: So if I don't select a radiobutton it still sends a value?

Comment: One radio button in a series should ALWAYS be selected. Although you CAN have none of them selected by default, I believe it's bad practice and may result in undefined behaviour depending on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

When the form is submitted, the content of the input fields is sent to the server.

If those input fields are empty, the server gets an empty string for each input -- but it gets something ; so, the `$_POST["start"], $_POST["end"], $_POST["multiplication"]` items are set -- even if they only contain empty strings.

You could check :

- If the fields contain an empty string : `if ($_POST["start"] === '')`
- Or if if contains only blank spaces : `if (trim($_POST["start"]) === '')`
- Or if they are [**`empty`**](https://www.php.net/empty) : `if (empty($_POST["start"]))`

Comment: Okay. I don't understand the difference between an empty string and when an item is not set which I assume is NULL.

Comment: An empty string means some information : it is an empty string *(which, in some case, could be a valid input)* ;;; a variable which is not set means no information at all.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. Can you give me an example of an empty value, a NULL value, a set variable and a variable which is not set?

Comment: empty : $a='0' or $a=null or $a=false or $a='' *(see the manual for more)* ;;; null : $a=null ;;; set variable : $a=... anything that is not null ;;; variable which is not set : try to read from $b without having given it any value before.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields aren't defined your code will print your message in the html before the `<html>` tag appears. Most browsers won't display it or display it in an unexpected place.

You should move the message display somewhere in the html where the user could see it.

And as other pointed out, except on the first call of the page the fields will have an empty value but still exists (and so `isset` will return `TRUE`)

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understand you right. It is

```
if(!isset($_POST["start"], $_POST["end"], $_POST["multiplication"])) {
    print "Please enter some values";
}
```

that works not as expected? It seems, that you assume an empty string means, that nothing is set, what is not true.

```
$x = "";
isset($x); // true
```

Use `empty()` or just `$_POST['start'] == ''` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what the difference between NULL and empty is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user700543: `null` is a special value, that means something like "nothing". Its the only value of the special type `null`. The function `empty()` tests -- as the name suggests -- if the value of a variable is empty, for example if its an empty string or array. `isset()` tests, if the variable is set at all and if its not `null`. Form fields (as long as they exists) are always strings, so you cannot test theire content with `isset()`

Comment: Sorry if I don't quite follow. The function empty() tests if the variable is blank i.e. the user did not specify any value but the function isset () tests if the value is set and if it is not null. What do you mean by set and if it is not null? What can be null?

Comment: Every variable can be `null`: `$var = null;`. Now `$var` is `null`. By "a variable is set" I meant, that it "exists" in at all: `isset($var); /* false */ $var = 12; isset($var); /* true */`.

Comment: Sorry for my noobness but I don't understand what you mean. Can you break it down for me in a lay person's example?